# How to program C++ to read a set amount of lines from a txt file?

Tags: c++

I could use some advice on how to get C++ to only read a set amount of lines from a txt file.
There are 365 lines in the file, and each line contains the number of steps taken during a
day. The first 31 lines are for January, then February and so on. Then I'm supposed to find the average of each month and display it. I'm having trouble trying to get the program to only read the first 31 then move on to the next month. Also I'm new to stack overflow so I apologize for any bad formatting.

```cpp
int main()
{
    int days;
    
    inFile.open("steps.txt"); // open file
    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << "Failure to open file" << endl;
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    days = jan(1);
    
}
int jan(int lineR)
{
    
    int sum, i;
    while (i != 31)
    {
        while (inFile >> lineR) // read line by line
        {
            
            i++;
            cout << lineR << endl;
            sum = lineR + sum;
            sum = sum / i;
            
        }
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
    return i;
}
```

Comment: _`while (inFile >> lineR )`_ use `while (std::getline(inFile ,lineR) )` instead.

Comment: Minor note about language: to "set upon" means to attack. The standard phrase for a fixed quantity is "set amount" (no "upon")

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
while (inFile >> lineR )// read line by line
```

You can switch to a for-loop with a counter:

```
for (int i = 0; inFile >> lineR && i < 31; i++ )
```

But for readability, [magic numbers should be avoided](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/56375/366708), so I'd actually replace that 31 with a variable:

```
const int DAYS_IN_MONTH = 31;
for (int i = 0; inFile >> lineR && i < DAYS_IN_MONTH; i++ )
```

Also, note that `inFile >> lineR` isn't *actually* reading the whole line. It's just reading the next `int` it can find (and possibly breaking terribly). To read a full line, you could make a string variable and use `std::getline`):

```
std::string line;
for (int i = 0; std::getline(inFile, line) && i < 31; i++ )
```

Comment: Thank you this helped!

Comment: Note to asker: Since 31 only applies to some months, you'll want to use a variable in its place. An array that lists the number of days in each month will make this a lot easier because now you can have a loop in a loop with the outer loop handling the month. February will be a pain since it has a variable number of days.

Comment: thank you, luckily our problem dose not include leap years.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    ifstream inFile;
    int sum = 0, lineCounter = 0, monthPointer = 0, x;
    inFile.open("steps.txt");
    int monthsArray[] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
    if (!inFile)
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to open file";
        exit(1);
    }

    while (inFile >> x)
    {
        if (lineCounter == monthsArray[monthPointer])
        {
            // se la riga è arrivata al limite del mese corrente allora stampo
            int avg = sum / lineCounter;
            std::cout << "Month " << monthPointer + 1 << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Avg = " << avg << std::endl;
            sum = 0;
            lineCounter = 0;
            monthPointer++;
        }
        sum = sum + x;
        lineCounter++;
    }

    inFile.close();
    std::cout << "_______" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Sum = " << sum << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Line Counter = " << lineCounter << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```